# SQL query only works from within the Android Emulator and nowhere else - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, flutter

**SOLVED:
i just deleted the username column and created it again, and the problem got solved.**

I'm developing a flutter app and everything works fine in the emulator, login, signup, fetching data and everything else.

now when i built the apk and installed it on a real device, the login is not working anymore and i know where the problem is, the problem is that the sql query not returning a result when sending username and password from any where else other than the emulator.

i tried postman, and got the same problem again, i even tried executing the query as is in the admin panel of the database and still nothing.

below is some images showing my problem.

**all the records in the users table:**

[image]

**the sql query execution: (MY PROBLEM)**

[image]

**NOTES:**

1. this query works like a charm in the emulator.
2. when trying to execute it using postman or the admin panel of the database it doesn't return any results.
3. everything else works great in all places.

**thanks in advance**

**EDIT:**

using other columns in the where clause executes fine only the username column has a problem and i don't know what is it.

Comment: Maybe some trailing spaces. Does `where trim(username) = 'belko'` work?

Comment: try where username like 'beko'?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, but i solved the problem and edited the question, thank you again

Comment: @AnirudhBagri thank you too my friend